# DocuSign management – integration/sql/excel/ideas?

Tags: docusignapi, document

I am looking for a way to better manage documents in DocuSign. The number of documents stored in DocuSign is growing and becoming increasingly difficult to organize. I want to see all documents in a centralized location so each document can be easily referenced. I am looking for a third-party platform that integrates DocuSign, or a way to export documents from DocuSign into an SQL database that can be opened in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are many answers to your question and Id like to offer just one at this point.
DocuSign Retrieve is a Windows application that you can use to gather documents from DocuSign for storage outside of DocuSign. You can use it as a standalone app or as part of other system using scripts that call it when you need to. You can find out more information about it in [this guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/retrieve-quick-start-guide).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read through the the DocuSign Retrieve guide and it has the extraction functions I am looking for; however, we are a Mac company. Do you know of other applications with similar extraction functions that work on Mac? (I am aware of parallels)

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a retrieve for the Mac. You can probably write it yourself or ask for a bid from a contractor. It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: If you found this response useful, would you mind marking it as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also check out DocuSign [Intelligent Insights](https://www.docusign.com/products/intelligent-insights).